# Average side length of a triangle with perimeter $p$

Tags: triangles, uniform-distribution, means, triangle-inequality

On the one hand, I think that by symmetry the average side of a triangle with given perimeter $p$ is $\frac{p}{3}$.

However (and here I'm probably mistaken), if I look at a side of the triangle, say $a$, by the triangle inequality it must be in the range $0<a<\frac{p}{2}$. Then, if the side length is uniformly distributed, this would imply that the average side length is $\frac{p}{4}$.

How can the second approach be corrected? (I assume the problem is that I wrongly assumed the distribution of $a$).

The reason I want to use the second approach is because more complex problems (for example, finding means of sizes that are a function of a side length) would require knowing how $a$ is distributed.

Comment: Before this question can be answered, you need to decide how your random triangle is being constructed. Are you selecting three random points somehow? Or are you selecting three random side lengths and rejecting them if they can't be made into a triangle? Or what?

Comment: I don't think that the side lengths can be uniformly distributed. Note that depending on the side length of the two other sides, the third one cannot be "just anything" ...

Comment: @TonyK I'm selecting three random side lengths and rejecting them is they can't make a triangle.

Comment: I see the problem now, because the choice of each side would be depending on the other choice.

Comment: Oh, hold on $-$ if $a+b+c=p$, then the average of $a,b,$ and $c$ is (by definition) $p/3$. Simple!

Comment: But, what if I'm given another condition, say $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. How would you go about calculating the average side length of a triangle with these conditions?